# Control pre sign-up behavior in AWS Cognito when an email already exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have a cognito user pool set up and am using the default sign-up work flow. I am trying to control the message response when an email already exists in the user pool. Currently it returns a message stating the email already exists which is frowned upon. I want to alter that response message however when I test it with a pre sign-up lambda trigger the lambda is bypassed. If I try a different email the lambda function is executed. Is it possible to control the response or is this something that can only be done with a custom sign-up form? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Here is my simple lambda function that is attached to the cognito user pool lambda triggers as a pre sign-up trigger.

```
export const handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.info(event);
  console.info(context);
  // TODO implement
  if (event) {
    var error = new Error("Test");
    
    callback(error, event);
  }
  
  callback(null, event);
};
```